# How can i create more network namespace?

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, clone, linux-namespaces

How to use `unshare()`, `clone()` to create lots of network namespace in linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just

```
if (unshare(CLONE_NEWNET) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create a new network namespace: %s\n",
                strerror(errno));
        goto out;
}
```